# string TLDID = gvTLDs.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; always returns 0 in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
string TLDID = gvTLDs.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

The code above is always returning 0 in the database. Below is how i am connecting it to the database

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FatshostsA2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Interests (TLDID, UserID)" + "values(@TLDID, @UserID)", conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TLDID", TLDID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["User"]);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

All of this is executed with the press of a button on my website. I am probably doing something wrong with the way i am calling the value of the cell from the selcted row.

Comment: How do you set the value of `gvTLDs.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text` ?

Comment: The instruction com.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed in the database.  When the table in the database has a primary key only one row can contain the value.  When you do an INSERT and the key already exists then no row are changed (the integer value will be zero) and you need to do an UPDATE.  If you do an UPDATE and the key is not in the database you will also get a zero and then you need to do an INSERT.

Comment: The query is doing an insert into the database. The rest of your code is trying to display a value from a grid. How do these two things relate to eachother? Your question makes no sense.